# Automatically enable emacs whitespace mode

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs 23.
How can I automatically enable emacs white space mode whenever I start emacs?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your init file (`~/.emacs`):

```
 (global-whitespace-mode)
```

Comment: It doesn't work for some modes. In this case — one can add the hook the modes with: `(mapc (lambda (language-mode-hook) (add-hook language-mode-hook (lambda () (whitespace-mode 1)))) '( comint-mode-hook minibuffer-inactive-mode-hook))`